# Why is Unity so slow?

Tags: 12.10, unity

I recently installed this 12.10 version. I am facing problem with the user interface. like opening browsers and opening dash home and typing in dash home bar and also it is very slow if I try to minimize them. But once I open the browser i do not see any problem like I can access net pretty fast as same as my windows 7. but only i am facing problems with UI screen while opening and minimizing. I did search in google. Someone said i need to edit the XORG.conf file but I do not see such file in the path "/etc/X11/". Can someone help me how to solve this?

My laptop specs are as below:

- Graphics: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
- Processor: Intel(R) core i5 @2.27GHZ
- System type: 64-bit
- Memory: 4 GB

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit Xorg.conf.

If you installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently, then it is normal that the minimization animation is slow. This was made on purpose by the designers. It is to show how minimization works.

You should see that the animation gets faster and faster with time. This is automatic.

Comment: Actually it is dead slow. not only minimizing if i click on any icon like dash Home it is taking exactly 6 sec to appear. and I did not install any drivers after installing ubuntu. i did check  additional drivers and it is showing "No Proprietary drivers" Do i need to install any drivers for my graphics card ?

Comment: I did below adjustments:  1. previously my hard disk (SCSI) is 20 GB. I expanded to 40 GB in VMware settings     
 2. In Display section of VMware previously I did not check the Accerlate 3D Graphics option now I selected the same.(I am guessing this must be the reason)
After i am done with above two changes I can see my system responding very fast Now my dash home appearing less than sec  
@Agmenor : Thank you for your reply and editing my question, giving appropriate tags
i am new to this ubuntu looking forward to explore more...

Comment: Nice! Enjoy Ubuntu!
I suggest you copy-paste your comment into an answer, so that others can benefit from your experience. ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you be running out of RAM? I like to be a bit of a derp at times, so I once wrote a program that creates a large memory leak. I was monitoring the CPU usage and RAM usage of the system constantly. When the system starts swapping, it grinds to a halt. Even though I have an SSD, that doesn't give the speed of RAM.

My CPU usage was at like 10%, but the RAM usage was to the point where if the kernel derped up, a kernel panic would have been prevalent.

When the kernel called SIGKILL on my application and terminated it, Unity became smooth again immediately.

When I was having this freezing problem, it would take 30 seconds for me to switch windows.

If you have more than 4GB of RAM, you're good. 2GB and under can be quite unuseable because the latest versions of Ubuntu suck up RAM with all the features they come with out of the box.

Another possibility is that you may have a frail GPU. Unity uses a whole lot of OpenGL, so a good graphics card is a necessity. If this problem persists, try Lubuntu. If you keep getting this problem, you're computer's specs aren't good enough for Ubuntu.

I myself have an i3, 6GB RAM, and HD 3000 GPU, so most of the latest computers have greater specs!